# Show that $u(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Omega$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\Omega\subset R^n$ is a bounded open domain and $u(x)$ is a smooth function that satisfies
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\Delta u+x_{1}u^{2}u_{x_1}=0 \text{ for all } u\in\Omega\\ 
u(x)=0 \text{ for all } x\in\partial\Omega
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Show that $u(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Omega$

**My attempt:**

By multiplying th first line with $u$ we have:
$I= \int\limits_{\Omega}u\Delta u+x_1u^3u_{x_1}dx=0$

And from Green's identity we have:
$\int\limits_{\Omega}u\Delta udx=-\int\limits_{\Omega}|Du|^2dx+\int\limits_{\partial\Omega}u\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}ds=-\int\limits_{\Omega}|Du|^2dx$ (since $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$)

Also:
$\int\limits_{\Omega}x_1u^3u_{x_1}dx=\frac{1}{4}\int\limits_{\Omega}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(x_1u^4)dx-\frac{1}{4}\int\limits_{\Omega}u^4dx$

Then by substituting in $I$,
$I=-\int\limits_{\Omega}|Du|^2dx-\frac{1}{4}\int\limits_{\Omega}u^4dx+\frac{1}{4}\int\limits_{\Omega}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(x_1u^4)dx=0$

So if we define, $$E(x_1)=\int\limits_{\Omega}x_1u^4dx$$
Then $\frac{d}{dx_1}E(x_1)=\int\limits_{\Omega}|Du|^2dx+\frac{1}{4}\int\limits_{\Omega}u^4dx\geq0$

and I couldn't proceed afterwards.. May be there is a different way to do this problem
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *integration by parts* in the second integral you should gain a vanishing boundary integral: in fact, you get:

$$\begin{split} \int_\Omega x_1 u^3 u_{x_1}\ \text{d} x &= \int_\Omega x_1 \ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \left[ \frac{1}{4}\ u^4\right]\ \text{d} x \\
&= \underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\int_{\partial \Omega} x_1\ u^4\ \nu_1\ \text{d} \sigma}_{=0} - \int_\Omega \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}[x_1]\ \frac{1}{4} u^4\ \text{d} x \\
&= - \frac{1}{4}\int_\Omega u^4\ \text{d} x
\end{split}$$

($\nu_1$ in the vanishing integral is the first coordinate of the exterior normal unit vector $\nu$ to the boundary $\partial \Omega$).

Therefore you have:

$$-\int_\Omega \left[ |\operatorname{D} u|^2 + \frac{1}{4} u^4\right]\ \text{d} x = 0$$

entailing $u=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: You’re welcome. ;-)